# @import sass directive doesn't work for me, (Undefined mixin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

rails 3.2, bootstrap 3.

I use [bootstrap sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and I can't do it work. 
I have this error

> Undefined mixin 'make-lg-column'.

in this file **app/assets/stylesheets/exam.css.scss**

```
...
.button-left{
  @include make-lg-column(4);
  display:inline;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
...
```

this is my **application.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "exam";
```

if I add these lines to **exam.css.scss** it works. But I don't want do it

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
```

Please any advice is welcome, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to compile the "exam" file as a part of application.css?

If I understand right, you should rename your file exam.css.scss -> _exam.scss  and you don't need to add any other import.

it happens because exam.css.scss is a seperate file and compiler don't know anything about applications.css.scss

Answer (score 0):

The mixin `make-lg-column` is defined within the `bootstrap/mixins;` file. In order to process the mixins file, you also need to provide the variables file. You can do 1 of 2 things:

1. Include the mixins and variables files within your **exam.css.scss** file even though it's not your preference.
2. You can copy the `make-lg-column` mixin out of the mixins file into the beginning of your **exam.css.scss** file.

> ```
> .make-lg-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width){
>   position: relative;
>   min-height: 1px;
>   padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
>   padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
>   @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
>     float: left;
>     width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
>   }
> }
> ```

**NOTE: You will have to redeclare your variables too.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't understand because I have to include `make-lg-column` again if [in this file of gem is included](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss#L2-L3). It is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question then. Are you trying to compile `exam.css.scss` on it's own or compile it into `application.css.scss`? If you want to compile `exam.css`, you will have to redeclare your variables & mixins. If you only want to compile `application.css` then you shouldn't have to redeclare variable and mixins. It looks like you're trying to compile `exam.css` though, correct?

Comment: I want to compile `application.css.scss`. I'm following [this advice](http://pivotallabs.com/structure-your-sass-files-with-import/).

Comment: Do you have a file in your `bootstrap` folder that rolls up all your imports? I see you're calling `@import: "bootstrap";`. Do you have a `bootstrap.scss` file that includes all your bootstrap files?

Comment: According with [gem documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass) `@import "bootstrap";` include all of Bootstrap's styles, mixins and variables!. So only use it. It's rare because after I put underscore to exam.css.scss -> _exam.. It worked.

Comment: the underscore means that the file is gonna be imported and compiled after in the new file, without the underscore it will compile before and the import it